# Pra que serve a função `reduce` em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, programação-funcional

Em quais casos é útil e como posso usar a função `reduce`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A função `reduce`, disponível no módulo built-in `functools`, serve pra "reduzir" um iterável (como uma lista) a um único valor.

É um paradigma um pouco mais comum em linguagens funcionais, mas que também é bastante útil em linguagens imperativas/orientadas a objetos como o Python.

Mas como assim, "reduz" uma lista?

---

Suponhamos que você tem uma lista `minha_lista`, que só contém números, e que você queira o resultado da multiplicação entre todos esses números. Um dos jeitos de fazer isso é com um for:

```
# Queremos 2 * 4 * 5 * 2, que é igual a 80
minha_lista = [2, 4, 5, 2]

produto_total = 1
for numero in minha_lista:
     produto_total *= numero

print(produto_total)  # 80
```

Isso funciona, mas também pode ser feito com `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

minha_lista = [2, 4, 5, 2]

def mult(x, y):
    return x * y

produto_total = reduce(mult, minha_lista)
print(produto_total)  # 80
```

Ou, de modo equivalente mas um pouco mais conciso, com uma função *lambda* (que nada mais é do que uma função definida em uma só expressão/linha):

```
from functools import reduce

minha_lista = [2, 4, 5, 2]

produto_total = reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, minha_lista)
print(produto_total)  # 80
```

Então o que está acontecendo aí? Se dermos uma olhada em "slow motion", o que acontece é o seguinte:

1. `reduce` recebe como argumento de função aplicada a função `mult` (ou a lambda, no segundo caso)
2. `reduce` recebe como iterável a lista `minha_lista`
3. `reduce` considera como `x` e `y`, respectivamente, os dois primeiros elementos de `minha_lista`: 2 e 4
4. `reduce` aplica a `x` e `y` a função `mult`, que multiplica um pelo outro: em `2 * 4`, o resultado é 8.
5. O resultado da aplicação da função (nosso 8) passa a ser `x`, e o próximo elemento não processado (5, terceiro elemento da nossa lista) passa a ser `y`
6. A função `mult` é aplicada a `x` e `y`: `8 * 5` retorna `40`, e esse valor retornado passa a ser nosso novo `x`
7. A função `mult` é aplicada pela última vez ao `x` e o último elemento da nossa lista, `2`. `40 * 2` nos retorna 80
8. Como não há mais elementos em que aplicar a função, `reduce` nos retorna o resultado final: 80, como esperado.

Resumindo, a função **aplica outra função sequencialmente e cumulativamente a uma lista (iterador), e "reduz" a lista a um só resultado final**.

---

Outro exemplo didático é o de calcular o valor mínimo de uma lista:

```
from functools import reduce

minha_lista = [2, 4, 5, 2, 1]

def achar_minimo(x, y):
    if x < y:
        return x
    else:
        return y

minimo = reduce(achar_minimo, minha_lista)
print(minimo)  # 1
```

Nesse caso, o primeiro argumento `x` é usado pra guardar o menor valor visto, e ele é comparado com os outros valores `y` da lista.

Digo que esse exemplo é didático porque já existe uma função equivalente no Python: a `min`. Ainda assim, acho que o exemplo é legal pra dar outra ideia do poder de `reduce`.

Além do mostrado acima, o `reduce` também aceita um terceiro argumento opcional, o `initial_value`. Como o nome indica, esse argumento pode ser dado como valor inicial, e é em efeito a mesma coisa do que botar esse valor no início da sua lista.

---

Esses exemplos são simples e podem parecer bobos, mas à medida que as funções aplicadas ficam mais complexas, usar o `reduce` pode ser uma boa pra diminuir o tamanho do código e deixá-lo mais claro. De qualquer modo, é uma boa ferramenta a se ter.

Comment: Acho que é importante acrescentar que o mais comum é usar o "reduce" com um terceiro parâmetro, representando o valor inicial para "x".

Comment: @jsbueno boa, adicionei um parágrafo sobre isso!